# reloadData in tableView makes performance slow

Tags: iphone

I'm working on the table view and I'm facing a problem such that my table is slowing down to display a data. What I have coded is

```
-(void) loadView {
     getDataForTableView();
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return items.count;
}
-(void) getDataForTableView {
    // This method will do some stuff and will return the count of items
    [self.tableView reloadData]
}
```

My table can reload and then display the content of **items** in table view. However, it is going to take a while to do this. How can we speed up the progress so that the table view will display data faster?

**UPDATE:**

What I did is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"shoppingListCell";
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    MyCustomCell.totalLabel.text = numberAsString;
    MyCustomCell.comment.text = currentItem.comment;
    return MyCustomCell;
}
```

Comment: How are you generating the cells?  I suspect you might not be reusing those in the correct manner.

Comment: Show us your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Is there any other code that gets executed when this happens?  Nothing you have shown so far would explain any slow down.

Comment: actually,I did fired a request to server and (void)getDataForTableView is a method which is returning me **items**

Comment: @dtuckernet : I can speed up the process my using performSelectorOnMainThread and I am passing method named **reloading**. In reloading, I do : [self.tableView reloadData]....I tried to convince myself but somehow I could not.. Please give me a hint if you know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your getDataForTableView() method is doing a server request, on the main thread, all UI will freeze until the request returns. If it is a synchronous request. If it is asynchronous, but your app is still waiting on it for reloading data, it won't be a UI freeze, but the interface will just be waiting for something.

I would do the request on a different thread or using NSInvocationOperation, and have it post a notification / call a callback when the request comes back. Just make sure that the notification handler does any/all talking to UIKit objects via performSelectorOnMainThread. Apple dictates all UIKit code has to execute on the main thread, and although sending messages to UIKit objects on other threads won't necessarily crash your app or cause a compiler warning, it will lead to very unpredictable behavior (and also maybe crashes).

From a user interface perspective, if you *must* only do the request at the time the table view is shown (for some valid reason), make sure you show a "loading" activity indicator (See UIActivityIndicatorView) or some such thing.

Ideally, though, you should load the data and cache it in the background, before the table is even shown. And check it periodically for staleness and get fresher data from the server when needed. Think about how foursquare or Path do this with venue data in their apps.